# Rotating QGIS Annotation layer text

Tags: qgis, annotation, rotate

I can't figure out how to rotate annotation text in QGIS (3.28.2).

This is not for a 'label', it's for text on an "Annotation" layer

Does anyone have advice on how to do it?

I can add rotated text in the layout view, but would prefer to have it as an annotation layer directly on the map.

Comment: Perhaps you can't rotate them: https://north-road.com/2021/10/21/introducing-annotation-layers-in-qgis-3-22/

Comment: The only rotation I have found was for the entire annotation layer and not by annotation, In the Layer Styling Panel, under "Draw effects" -> "Effect type" -> "Transform" -> "Rotation". Ps: it not really functional since adding new annotations moves the others so it is kinda broken